# How to convert List <T> data to Object [] type

Tags: c#

Model:

```
public class CodeInfo
    {
        public String CODE { get; set; }
        public String CODE_NAME { get; set; }
        public String P_CODE { get; set; }
        public String P_CODE_NAME { get; set; }
        public int CODE_TYPE { get; set; }
        public int CODE_LEVEL { get; set; }
        public int MAX_LEVEL { get; set; }
        public String DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
        public String CREATE_USER { get; set; }
        public DateTime CREATE_TIME { get; set; }
        public String DISABLE_YN { get; set; }
    }
```

Questions:

```
List<CodeInfo> codeInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CodeInfo>>(applyObj["list"].ToString());

Object[] test = ????
```

I want the result :

test[] :

{CODE, CODE_NAME, P_CODE .....}

I want to get only the current value in the model and put it into an Object array (see the model's data type).

Comment: It would probably be easier to do this if you deserialized into a `List<JObject>`.

Comment: I'm don't know why do you want to cast it to `object`, but here you go: `var test = codeInfo.Cast<object>().ToArray()`

Comment: Do you mean to flatten all the components of each codeInfo into a single object array?  E.g.  If `codeInfo` has 2 items in the collection, you want both the values of `CODE` ?

Comment: Could you explain *why* you want to do this?   Are you trying to call an API that needs an `object[]`?  What do you hope to do with the object[] ?

Comment: What I want to do is
DataTable.Rows.Add (new Object [] {...})
I want to add a row in the form

Currently my data type is List type. Therefore, it seems to need conversion to Object [].

Comment: Rather than getting all of the object's property names and values.
I want to get only the value and make it an object [].

Comment: Your data type is _not_ `List`. The data type of the thing you want to turn into an `Object[]` is **`CodeInfo`**. You just have **multiple** of them, and that's why they're in a `List`.

Answer (score 1):

You can deserialize to `List<Object>`:

```
List<Object> codeInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Object>>(applyObj["list"].ToString());
```

Or

You can deserialize to `Object[]`:

```
Object[] codeInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object[]>(applyObj["list"].ToString());
```

Or

With linq:

```
Object[] test = codeInfo.ToArray<Object>();
```

Comment: Rather than getting all of the object's property names and values. I want to get only the value and make it an object [].

Comment: What are you mean to get only the value

Comment: As a result of the above comment:
{code: "asp", code_name: "ddd", code_level: 3, ...}
I want the result :
{"asp", "ddd", 3}

Comment: You want an Object [] that contains only results, not property names.

Comment: Your purpose is not so clear. The array contains the values and not "property names"

Comment: OP means the values of the properties in their object, not the objects themselves.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you want to get an array of arrays of property values. Then you can use this code:

```
var test = codeInfo.Select(i => new[] { i.CODE, i.CODE_NAME, i.P_CODE, i.P_CODE_NAME, i.CODE_TYPE,
                                        i.CODE_LEVEL, i.MAX_LEVEL, i.DESCRIPTION, i.CREATE_USER,
                                        i.CREATE_TIME, i.DISABLE_YN }).ToArray()
```

Comment: Do note this gives an `Object[][]` as result. The problem is OP doesn't seem to realise they still have to iterate over the multiple objects that are retrieved _anyway_ in order to add them to the `DataTable`, rendering a `Select` like this rather moot.

Answer (score 1):

You have a logical flaw here. The `List<CodeInfo>` contains *all* your data, while that `Object[] test` you want to go to is the contents of just *one* `CodeInfo` object.

Do the sensible thing. Just use a `foreach` to fill it up, and create the array of properties manually. You need a separate `DataTable.Rows.Add` call per line *anyway*.

```
List<CodeInfo> codeInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CodeInfo>>(applyObj["list"].ToString());
foreach (CodeInfo info in codeInfo)
    DataTable.Rows.Add(new Object[] { info.CODE, info.CODE_NAME, info.P_CODE, ... });
```